# Picking up a variable from inside an if-statement

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

I'm trying to learn JavaScript but I've gotten stuck.

[Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating the code below](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/FP8T9/).

The problem here is that I want a function or something to calculate the total, but I do not know how to pick up the variable from inside the if-statement.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function funky(){
                var mengde = document.getElementById("options").value;
                var valgt = document.getElementById("fruit").value;

                if(valgt == "banan") {
                    mengde*=10;
                    document.getElementById("totalt1").innerHTML = mengde;
                }
                if(valgt == "eple") {
                    mengde*=20;
                    document.getElementById("totalt2").innerHTML = mengde;
                }
                if(valgt == "melon") {
                    mengde*=30;
                    document.getElementById("totalt3").innerHTML = mengde;
                }
                if(valgt == "appelsin") {
                    mengde*=40;
                    document.getElementById("totalt4").innerHTML = mengde;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="options" type="text"></input>
        <select id="fruit">
            <option>Velg Frukt!</option>
            <option value="banan">Banan</option>
            <option value="eple">Eple</option>
            <option value="melon">Melon</option>
            <option value="appelsin">Appelsin</option>
            <option value="totis">Totalt</option>
        </select>
        <button onclick="funky()">Submit!</button>
        <p id="totalt1"></p>
        <p id="totalt2"></p>
        <p id="totalt3"></p>
        <p id="totalt4"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can pick up variables inside an if-statement just as you would do anywhere else.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve over what you've done. I've put it into a http://jsfiddle.net/BXyDx/ to play about with

Comment: Hang on, I think I get it. Are you trying to create like a shopping list with a total for all the items? Like 10 bananas, 5 apples total  cost 200 sort of thing?

Comment: @owen79 Yes! That is exactly what I'm trying to do!

Comment: @owen79 do you know how to do it? Sorry for my last answer the first time, i have an exam tomorrow and can't find the answer anywhere!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for something like this (although not the nicest javascript I'm trying to keep it similar to the approach you started out with)

http://jsfiddle.net/YZBL7/

```
 if(valgt == "banan") {
       total = mengde + " banan costs " + mengde * 10;
 }

 //....
 document.getElementById("totalt1").innerText += total + "\n";
```

Comment: Not exactly what i was going for, i want to add total1+total2+total3+total4.

Comment: Yeah, updated here http://jsfiddle.net/YZBL7/3/ mark as answer when happy please!